# Populating segment to and from columns with roadnames without manually typing each name in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have been given three shapefiles. One is a road centerline file with roadnames containing all the roads in a town (55k+ edges). One is an original file with 9316 edges that contain to and from fields indicating the intersecting road name. The last is a new shapefile that was created containing 1300 edited edges that have been either merged, split or some combination. The to and from fields still contain the original to and from field data, which is now incorrect.

Is there any way to populate to and from field for the new edges without having to manually enter each roadname?

Comment: It's not really clear what your data is, such questions are best provided with images along with your text description. That said may be you can extract centroids of lines and then use a spatial join to pass over the attribution?

Comment: I am trying to think of how to better explain it. I have fields in my data for to and from - meaning that if a segment runs from Oak St to Elm St the "to" would be Oak and the "From" would be Elm. But before the data was edited the segment ran from Cedar St to Elm St. So I need to change the To from Cedar St to Oak St. The data was created mostly by merging shorter segments and the process they used kept the old to and from info. Is there some way to populate the name of the intersecting streets from the intersecting edges. I can't figure out how to add pics :/